# Calculate Derivative of Function at a Point in R

Tags: r, derivative

Reading through [this documentation](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/numericDeriv.html) in R, I don't understand how to take a derivative of the function at *a specific point*.

[They do it here in C](https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Numerical-Differentiation-functions.html#Numerical-Differentiation-functions) (with gsl_deriv_central/forward/backward), but I was wondering if there is an equivalent in R?

Comment: The R documentation you point to is for taking the symbolic derivative of a function. The C documentation is for taking a numerical derivative.   Which do you want to do?  Which function do you want to differentiate?

Comment: ah good point! numerical!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just install the package `numDeriv` and use the `grad` function. Here are a few simple examples that are easy to check.

```
library(numDeriv)

grad(sin, 1:3)
[1]  0.5403023 -0.4161468 -0.9899925
cos(1:3)
[1]  0.5403023 -0.4161468 -0.9899925


f = function(x) x^2 + 2*x +3
grad(f, 1:3)
[1] 4 6 8
2*(1:3) + 2
[1] 4 6 8
```

Comment: Seems to work in base with OP's linked function: `numericDeriv(quote(sin(x)), "x", as.environment(list(sin = sin, x = as.numeric(1:3))))` or similar.

Comment: I missed `numericDeriv`  in that documentation.    @Frank.   Please add as an answer and I will delete this one.

Comment: Nah, it's fine. I'm not sure if my answer is even correct. I have never used the function before and was just having a look after clicking the OP's link. I'm not sure why I get a gradient matrix while you get a vector, for example. Feel free to add it or some more correct variant of it.

Comment: @Frank Yes, the gradient matrix is odd and confusing.  I will leave this.   Thanks.